# jquery ui draggable changes the width automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am following through [jquery ui docs](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) to make the divs draggable and sortable. And it does work for dragging and sorting. But when I take out a div from draggable to sortable, the width of the draggable changes and does not retain the width its supposed to be.

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/doxyNR)

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#grid-main_content').sortable({
        revert:true
    });

    $('#block-list .block').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#grid-main_content',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert:'invalid'
    });
})
```

And if I inspect the element which I dragged to the sortable, I can see that an inline style is given to the draggable block with a width (by jquery).

How can I maintain the style the block already has? Thank you.

Comment: So what you need,keep the width equal for both

Comment: @Vijay I need the block which I dragged to the sortable to have the width of the same size of other blocks in `#grid-main_container`.

Comment: You have another css file.

Comment: @Vijay No just the ones that's on the codepen demo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use draggables' [`start` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start), to maintain specific style of the *helper*

```
$('#block-list .block').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#grid-main_content',
    helper : 'clone',
    revert : 'invalid',
    start  : function(event, ui){
        $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-helper");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-helper {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbeWaX)

Comment: Yes. Its working. But it just covers up the the whole width of the browser when I drag it. It does however retain the width inside `#grid-main_container` but is it possible to have the width of the draggable block to maintain even when its dragged? Like the ones with your comment with jquery ui 1.10.4 .

Comment: You can use `.ui-draggable-dragging` in the latest jQuery UI, removing the need for custom JavaScript.

Comment: Neither this nor Steven Kaspar's solution worked for me with a draggable `<tr>` in Chrome. It seems an absolutely positioned `<tr>` won't contain its `<td>`s properly. If you set a background colour or border on the `<tr>, it will have the right width, but the table cells will leave a gap on the right.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Just set it to the width of the draggable element

```
$('.selector').draggable({
   helper: 'clone',
   start: function(event, ui){
      $(ui.helper).css('width', `${ $(event.target).width() }px`);
   }
})
```

that way you don't have add the CSS

Answer (score 0):

I just create a [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNmLEN)

Any way take a look at this,and copy the codes if it seems to be working.

if you need the lower portion of the div back to its original size,Please change

```
#grid-main_content {
width:80%;
```

Comment: Yes,I also added this code + the width,But width is not clear in Artur code.